# Navigating to a screen from a component react native

Tags: react-native

Hi I am trying to go the profile page when a user clicks on the picture of the user. I get an error when I use onPress and navigation.navigate.

This is the App.js Structure very simply only two screens.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import HomeProfile from "./components/HomeProfile";

const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false,
        title: null
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTintColor: "white",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#161E33",
          borderBottomWidth: 0
        },
        title: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <MainStack />;
  }
}

export default createAppContainer(MainStack);
```

This is the component that I use for the top half of the page So I don't have too much code in the Home page. Everything is hardcoded at the moment

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard
} from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";

const HomeProfile = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.background}
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1080721/pexels-photo-1080721.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
          }}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Profile")}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{
              uri:
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80"
            }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.name}>Abby Smith</Text>
          <Text style={styles.unit}>Slater 116 #278</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};


export default HomeProfile;
```

This is part of the home page where it is the main and the default screen and this is where I import the component.

```
  const [contactModal, setContactModal] = useState(false);
  const [announcementsModal, setAnnouncementsModal] = useState(false);
  const [maintenanceModal, setMaintenanceModal] = useState(false);
  const [accessModal, setAccessModal] = useState(false);
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <HomeProfile />
```

ERROR MESSAGE IS--

> TypeError: Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Comment: add ```HomeProfile``` to your ```MainStack ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the navigation props to **HomeProfile** inorder to use navigation.navigate.

> `<HomeProfile navigation={navigation}/>`

```
const [contactModal, setContactModal] = useState(false);
  const [announcementsModal, setAnnouncementsModal] = useState(false);
  const [maintenanceModal, setMaintenanceModal] = useState(false);
  const [accessModal, setAccessModal] = useState(false);
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <HomeProfile navigation={navigation} /> //====here
```

or simply, you can import **withNavigation** from react-navigation and wrap withNavigation HOC with HomeProfile Component like

> withNavigation(HomeProfile)

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';

const HomeProfile = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.background}
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1080721/pexels-photo-1080721.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
          }}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Profile")}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{
              uri:
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80"
            }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.name}>Abby Smith</Text>
          <Text style={styles.unit}>Slater 116 #278</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};


export default withNavigation(HomeProfile); //check here
```